# get attribute accessor only for specific method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, accessor

I want to modify some values of my query result for API call. here's my query

```
public function modules()
{
    Module::select('id','name','image')->get()->toJson();
}
```

so I want to modify `image` value, add full path to it. I added accessor

```
public function getImageAttribute($image)
{
    return asset($image);
}
```

and it works fine, but the problem is now it will be affecting this column every time i try to retrieve it. is there way to use this accessor(`getImageAttribute`) only for `modules` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get rid of the accessor and update the image path inside the `modules` method.

```
public function modules()
{
    return Module::select('id', 'name', 'image')->get()->map(function ($module) {
        $module->image = asset($module->image);
        return $module;
    })->toJson();
}
```

Comment: just couple of minutes, and I will be able to accept it

Comment: much appreciated